# Having trouble deploying Google Cloud Function to create PDFs

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to create a Google Cloud Function that will generate PDFs from a Google Docs template. I used [a blog post as guidance](https://cgarethc.medium.com/using-google-docs-and-drive-as-a-pdf-template-engine-with-node-js-on-google-cloud-functions-b2ab9155e308) to actually write the code.

I created a function in Google Cloud Functions, and in the index.js file, similar to the code in the blog post. I also updated the package.json code shown below.

I am very new to Google cloud functions and when I go to Trigger > URL, I get the message "PDF Failed To Generate". I have the Google Drive and Google Docs API installed as part of my GCP project this is under.

This is the error I'm getting in the Cloud Shell terminal:

Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The drive.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .'

My questions are: 1) Do I simply open a new terminal in Cloud Shell and follow the instructions on the link provided by Google? 2) Is there anything else I need to do or set up? 3) This type of function should only run as an authenticated function, right? For the first test I had it set up as unathenticated so I could Trigger it via URL 4) I've also read I have to do some sort of npm install but I'm not sure what that is in relation to this project.

package.js code

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
    "googleapis": "132.0.0"
  }
}
```